# localhost wordpress accepts my post. but not displayes with my changed permalink

Tags: permissions, apache2, lamp, localhost, wordpress

I have installed wordpress in my ubuntu desktop 14.04 and LAMP server installed it. that is in the directory /var/www/public/wordpress. after the installation has been completed the site works good.after i changed my default permalink to %postname% the result as follows

> Not Found The requested URL /wordpress/my-first-post/ was not
>   found on this server. Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port
>   80

also I did changed the permissions of the folder /var/www to read and write for all users. even though I got the same error. please help me. also I tried the previous solutions. but any of them not working for me. please help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you're better off at stackoverflow for questions like these.

Now can you check if you have mod_rewrite enabled?
Create a simple php file and add this code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Now visit that file and search the page (CTRL+F) for mod_rewrite.

If not enabled run this code:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

And restart apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Or

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: yes these are all work better.but i can't change my permalink from my default format.

Comment: Not sure what permission you gave, but try: sudo chmod 777 .htaccess